# getting last two items from a link

Tags: jquery

i have a link where i need to extract some information. I am trying to figure out some kind of regex which can fetch the first portion of the string and remove it and then after the question mark remove that

need to extract the last two items from the link

```
http://exampke.com/9.php?type=121&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2
```

i am trying to detect sortby and sortorder, how should i do that, i basically tried using regex but that is only showing me the 1 & 2 changed values so i am lost how to get the

`sortBy=1&sortOrder=2` from the url

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
    var link = "http://exampke.com/9.php?type=121&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2";
    var vals = link.split("?")[1].split(/&|=/).splice(2);
    var res = vals[0].concat("="+vals[1]).concat("&"+vals[2]+"="+vals[3]);
```

```js
    var link = "http://exampke.com/9.php?type=121&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2";
    var vals = link.split("?")[1].split(/&|=/).splice(2);
    var res = vals[0].concat("=" +vals[1]).concat("&" + vals[2] + "=" + vals[3]);
    document.write(res)
```

Comment: it did alsmost but i just get the 1,2, it did not picked sortby and sortorder, that is required

Comment: ok i changed Number to String and got this i alert: sortBy,1,sortOrder,2 can i change it to & and = like : sortBy=1&sortOrder=2

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://exampke.com/9.php?type=121&sortBy=1&sortOrder=2'

var what = url.search('\\&');

var result = url.slice(what + 1, url.length);
```

Your result variable now contains: sortBy=1&sortOrder=2